# Accessing multiple request params with the same name in Symfony2

Tags: post, symfony, request

I'm posting the following values to a Symfony2 web page:

> code=-1&tracking=SRG12891283&description=Error&code=0&tracking=SRG19991283&description=Label Printed.

Note the duplicates - there could be any number of code/tracking/description 'pairs'.

In Symfony, when I do the following, it only outputs the last set of values:

```
foreach($request->request->all() as $key => $val){
    $this->m_logger->debug($key . ' - ' .$val);
}
```

i.e.

> code = 0
>   tracking = SRG19991283
>   desription = Label Printed.

I'm assuming this is because the request class stores the parameters in key/value pairs and so subsequent params are simply overwriting the previous ones.

Any idea how I can access all of these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP in the $_REQUEST, $_POST, and $_GET arrays will overwrite a duplicated variable name with the last definition of the variable. Symfony2 as a result, exhibits the same behavior.

For example given the code.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test1" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="test2" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="test2" value="3"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, the output is

```
array(0) {
}
array(2) {
  ["test1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["test2"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(2) {
  ["test1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["test2"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Calling the page with the query string `?test1=1&test2=2&test2=3` the result is:

```
array(2) {
  ["test1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["test2"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(0) {
}
array(2) {
  ["test1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["test2"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

The only way to resolve this issue yourself would be to pass the variables as a query string (GET), in which case you could retrieve the query string and parse it yourself. This might not be appropriate if you're handling user input.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "array-like" syntax in your parameters, Symfony should do what you want.

For example, consider a querystring of `?code[0]=a&code[1]=b&code[2]=c`.

`$request->query->get('code');` in Symfony would return an array like this:

`[
  0 => "a",
  1 => "b",
  2 => "c",
]`

... which I think is what you want?  (Albeit this is a simpler example.)

Comment: And if you were building the posting side in Symfony too, you'd set a route parameter of `'code' => ['a','b','c']` to get that querystring.